# AG Grid - Icons not found

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG Grid with React and the pagination icons are being displayed as squares.

[image: missing icons]

**Dependencies:**

```
"ag-grid-community": "^29.2.0",
"ag-grid-react": "^29.2.0",
```

**`App.tsx` imports**

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

**Component**

```
<div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: "calc(100% - 108px)", width: "100%"}}>
    <AgGridReact
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        onModelUpdated={onModelUpdated}
    />
</div>
```

I found in the examples they also load an `agGridMaterial` font but this doesn't fix it. I was expecting this to be part of `ag-theme-alpine.css`

```
.ag-theme-alpine {
  --ag-icon-font-family: agGridMaterial;
}

/* content of agGridMaterialFont.css: */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'agGridMaterial';
  src: url(data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The CSS isn't being overridden:

[image: css not overridden]

How can I display the icons for AG Grid?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this is the definition that finally worked for me :

```
:root {
     --ag-icon-font-family: "agGridMaterial";
}
```